# What does "ha" event in nodejs-mongodb-native@2.x mean?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replicaset

I'm using MongoDB with a replica set with RF=3. There's an event "ha" in the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/ReplSet.html#event:ha) and as I see its impact on update op is huge:

```
[Wed Apr 29 2015 09:00:13 GMT+0300 (MSK)] [pid 7251] update took 0ms for uuid 08ecd93346daa1b8b6fef1772cea0469
[Wed Apr 29 2015 09:00:13 GMT+0300 (MSK)] [pid 7251] update took 1ms for uuid ea9a71aa09f0a8c3a169dcbb895e023d
[Wed Apr 29 2015 09:00:13 GMT+0300 (MSK)] [pid 7251] update took 1ms for uuid c4b51c3c1e7c18ab9c4f1e410af26a1b
[Wed Apr 29 2015 09:00:14 GMT+0300 (MSK)] [pid 7251] [event ha] ["start",{"norepeat":false,"id":8,"state":{"primary":"...","secondaries":["...", "..."]}}]
[Wed Apr 29 2015 09:00:14 GMT+0300 (MSK)] [pid 7251] [event ha_connect] ["start",{"norepeat":false,"id":8,"state":{"primary":"...","secondaries":["...", "..."]}}]
[Wed Apr 29 2015 09:00:15 GMT+0300 (MSK)] [pid 7251] update took 2124ms for uuid 07de843901cf5bc107f11e9965204920
[Wed Apr 29 2015 09:00:15 GMT+0300 (MSK)] [pid 7251] update took 2122ms for uuid 021c149b4a5272ef7b49296667484e1b
[Wed Apr 29 2015 09:00:15 GMT+0300 (MSK)] [pid 7251] update took 2122ms for uuid d5a7cfcc47aa5c238d33f2257edab674
```

As far as I see, this event comes from mongodb-core. But what's the meaning of this event? Is replica set connection lost every N seconds and restored?

Comment: ha means high availability. ([source](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/replset.html)) [Documentation about this feature](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-high-availability/).